# MySQL Query results

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

Table name : Students. 
The Table i have:

```
mysql> SELECT * from Students;
+-----------+-------------+-------+
| Rollno    | Name        | Marks |
+-----------+-------------+-------+
| 251602122 | Sumit Tyagi |    70 |
| 251602121 | parveen     |    90 |
+-----------+-------------+-------+
```

Following query returns the following result even 8 is not a attribute.

```
mysql> select 8 from Students;
+---+
| 8 |
+---+
| 8 |
| 8 |
+---+
```

Similarly

```
mysql> SELECT 'some_string' from Students;
+-------------+
| some_string |
+-------------+
| some_string |
| some_string |
```

I just want to know why this happens.

Comment: you are just select a literal value each time you have rows in tables (number and value in quotes are literal values and are selected as they are)  and of course the result is right ..

Comment: Why "MySql wrong query result" is the title, if you do not know the behavior?

Comment: I understand the question isn't a very interesting one because is a basic sql stuff, but the question isn't bad to leave too many negative. The question is well written and OP is trying to learn.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza The downvote arrow mouseover text says "does not show any research effort". A simple google 'sql select' explains this, let alone 'sql select constant'. The question just wastes people's time. If the OP thinks such posts don't explain "why" then they should explain what they mean by "why" & their post is "unclear"--more mouseover text.

Comment: @philipxy When you dont know the subject is hard to find the correct words for use in google. I rather give the OP the benefit of the doubt. I myself have make question and when see the answer feel stupid for the simple that was. But is only after you learn that become obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query returns one line for every record in your table.

But you don't select data from those record. You just select the number `8` for each line. And this gets returned.

Comment: but why this get returned?

Comment: I think is easy to understand if you do `SELECT name, 8`. This happen because you can always create additional field columns if need calculations like `SELECT name, 2*marks`

Answer (score 1):

Select statement looks for column name in a table. You can make sure SQL look for a column name in a table by using `TableName.ColumnName`.

In the example you wrote, you are asking for a constant or hardcoded value `8`/`some_string` to be returned from the table which is not the column name. So it will return the hardcoded or constant value you asked for, the number of times equal to number of rows in your table.

If you want to make sure it look for the column name, use the syntax I mentioned as `TableName.ColumnName`. You can also provide an alias for your table. So in the example above, if you use the syntax as

```
SELECT Students.8 from Students;
```

or

```
SELECT s.8 FROM Students s;
```

It will look for column name as `8` instead of constant or hardcoded value `8`.

If I am not wrong, it is a best practice to use `TableName.ColumnName` or `alias.ColumnName` while writing queries as it checks for column name in that particular table.

Comment: `table.column` is not a matter of "forcing"; SQL lets you use just `column` if and only if there is just one table with that column.